# how can i fix this error?

Tags: asp.net

im a newbie in `asp.Net` and i got some trouble with code
i have a code like this:

```
public class Log : AbstractLog
{
    private void Init()
    {
        base.IdentityColumn = "base_log_id"; 
    }
    public int LogId
    {
        get { return base.GetValueAsInt("base_log_id"); }
        private set { base.SetValue("base_log_id", value); }
    }
}
```

i just get and set value in a table named `base_log_id`, and if i cover `// AbtractLog` after building it got this error:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for GetValueAsInt,
'object' does not contain a definition for SetValue,
'object' does not contain a definition for IdentityColumn.
```

actually i have no code in `AbtractLog` class
so what should i write in `AbstractLog` ?
I'm using visual studio 2005

Comment: More information is required about what is "base"?? From the errors it is clear that the class of "base" doesn't contain the property and methods you are using in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method that is not in the base class, the problem, you're not extending the correct class, o the class you're extending hasn't those members or has them with private visibility, if you can post more code, and give more explanation, it would be usefull.

See you.